# How can i insert and update New Task and Notes in Lead in Salesforce

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, salesforce

I am using salesfoce sdk .can anybody tell me how can i insert and update New Task in salesforce in iphone sdK.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this website url! I tried to insert and update the data to salesforce and it is working fine! https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS

Comment: i have followed that link also...and it is working fine ...but problem is how can i insert files in salesforce and how can i get files from salesforce..